# Does anyone know how to remove the grind adjustment dial from the Eureka Mignon Perfetto?

Tags: grinder

I have an Eureka Mignon Perfetto and I really hate its "easy setting" dial: it's too sensitive and it makes any precise adjustment impossible.

I would like to remove it from the threaded adjustment rod and exchange it for the standard dial that the Silenzio or Specialita' use.

After a bit of searching around, I found out that there is a removable plastic cap on top of the dial.
Once open it reveals the adjustment gears: a metal traveler that seems to be screwed to the threaded rod, actuated by the outside, rotating, plastic dial.
I tried to unscrew this metal part but it doesn't seem to loosen and I don't want to break anything.

tl;dr: as per title, has anyone ever managed to remove this abomination of a knob from a Perfetto and replace it with the standard knob from the Silenzio/Specialita'?